# An error occurred while running .click() command on <input[type="submit"]>: from target frame detached in NightwatchJS

Tags: javascript, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js, end-to-end, nightwatch

I'm getting this error in Nightwatch when trying to click submit in an iframe

this is my code:

```
.perform(() => {
    client.getAttribute('#myiframe', 'id', result => {
        client
            .frame(result.value)
            .setValue('input[name="username"]', 'user')
            .setValue('input[name="password"]', 'password)
            .click('input[type="submit"]')
    })
})
```

it's sporadically happening too

anyway I can fix this?

I'm using latest version of nightwatch (^1.3.5) and chromedriver (^83.0.0)

Comment: are these values set correctly? did you try adding some pause before submit?

Comment: yeh values are deffo correct. and it's submitting into the iframe, just the test is failing

Comment: what error do you see for failure?

Comment: the title of this post is the error message. I know that isn't overly helpful to you but that's why I posted here because it didn't seem helpful to me either :/

Comment: did you try frame as per the docs? the docs says your interation with frame should be a callback?  

this.demoTest = function (browser) {
   browser.frame('<ID>', function(result) {
     console.log(result);
   });
}